# How to dynamically render list of components without re-rendering entire list with every new addition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to render a list of components that have a 1:1 relationship with some objects in my redux store.

My current code is:

```
  props.images.forEach(imageFile => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);

    const newStyles = { 
      left: `${leftPosition}%`,
      top: `${topPosition}%`
    }

    previewFloats.push(
      <div className="Preview" style={{...style, ...newStyles}} key={v4()}></div>
    )
  });

  return(
    previewFloats
  )
```

Edit: Example here ([codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcnulty-0rrjz](http://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcnulty-0rrjz))

The problem being that performance takes a pretty big hit rendering an entire list of background images as the list grows.

What is a better way to achieve this?

Edit: still unsure why background-image src is triggering a re-render, but the suggestion to use an `<img>` element instead has things working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Dergash on Github I've discovered that the problem is not that my list is re-rendered.

Because I am creating a new URL every time with URL.createObjectURL inside of my component and because 'backgroundImage' does not do image prefetching whereas src attribute does I am seeing the flicker.

So my mistake was not creating the URL first and then passing it down into the component.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-http-8vrgv

More details: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16187

Answer (score 2):

`Array.map()` allows dynamic rendering of elements in React, so that only those who change their props will re-render (as explained in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)).

If you'll use this method - rather than create the full array and render it fully - React will only re-render elements that are supposed to be updated:

```
props.images.map((imageFile, index) => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);

    const newStyles = { 
      left: `${leftPosition}%`,
      top: `${topPosition}%`
    }

    return (
      <div className="Preview" style={{...style, ...newStyles}} key={index}></div>
    )
});
```

Note that I've modified the `key` property of each element in the array. It should be unique and I didn't know what `v4()` is, so I just used the array indices.
React's documentation actually explains really well about these:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed

Comment: I threw up an example - unless I'm doing it wrong it seems that method still re-renders entire list.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcnulty-0rrjz (relevant code in Preview.js)

Comment: I don't understand what your code does, so it's hard to reproduce. Did you try adding `console.log` to each of the `map`'s inner functions?

Comment: That link has a minimal example in it so you hopefully don't have to reproduce it.

What would I be looking for in the logs?

Comment: @colemars The amount of times the code is being executed, hence the amount of elements being re-rendered.

Comment: The code is executed the length of the array on every update.

Comment: @colemars If you're interested in knowing the amount of times a component was rendered, the most straight-forward way to test it would be to add a **side-effect**, i.e. a `console.log` print that takes place on every element rendering

Comment: it's expected that `<Preview>` is still re-render. so Virtual DOM is generated to compare with. but DOM should be updated only for single `image`(if you provide proper `key` - and you do).

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is with 'key' property of react components. It's built for such cases
Assuming this is render part of your component, you should have something like this:

```
return this.props.images.map(imageFile => (
    <div className="Preview" key={imageFile}></div>
))
```

Assuming imageFile is a unique string. This way react will rerender your virtual dom but it'll recognise that there is no need to dom update for same elements with same key property

Comment: I updated it here(https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcnulty-0rrjz) but it still seems they are all re-rendering. Notice the white flash on all images when a new image is added.

Comment: Now checking your copepen, I see the issue. I believe you should use regular img element to stop flickering. Because with key properties, react doesn't render it. I'm not sure where flicker comes from but, if you just change your div to img and give appropriate src, it just works without flickering

Comment: adding a pre-generated key to my array elements worked for me. it removed the re-rendering of the other elements.